Django PayPal webhooks verification testing
I want to create my own realization of paypalrestsdk.WebhookEvent.verify that I'm using right now, so I want to create test, that uses request from PayPal webhook that my app already handled, for verification tests.
My question is - Is it possible to verify webhook that is already verified (so basically I just provide already verified request to paypalrestsdk.WebhookEvent.verify).
I created test that uses data that was used for real webhook verification for paypalrestsdk.WebhookEvent.verify. Symbol "*" is used for confidential info.
class MockRequest:
    def __init__(self, meta, body):
        self.META = meta
        self.body = body


class TestVerifyEvent(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.body = {"id":"*","event_version":"1.0","create_time":"*","resource_type":"sale","event_type":"PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED","summary":"Payment completed for $ 10.0 USD","resource":{"billing_agreement_id":"I-2CSK9W3P6C29","amount":{"total":"10.00","currency":"USD","details":{"subtotal":"10.00"}},"payment_mode":"INSTANT_TRANSFER","update_time":"*","create_time":"*","protection_eligibility_type":"ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE","transaction_fee":{"currency":"USD","value":"0.84"},"protection_eligibility":"ELIGIBLE","links":[{"method":"GET","rel":"self","href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/*"},{"method":"POST","rel":"refund","href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/*/refund"}],"id":"1TV06398E1048801N","state":"completed","invoice_number":""},"links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/*","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/*/resend","rel":"resend","method":"POST"}]}

        self.META = {
                'HTTP_PAYPAL_TRANSMISSION_ID': 'verified transmission id',
                'HTTP_PAYPAL_TRANSMISSION_TIME': 'verified transmission time',
                'HTTP_PAYPAL_CERT_URL': 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/*',
                'HTTP_PAYPAL_TRANSMISSION_SIG': 'verified transmission signature',
                'HTTP_PAYPAL_AUTH_ALGO': 'SHA256withRSA'
            }
        self.mock_request = MockRequest(self.META, str(self.body).encode('utf-8'))

    def test_verify_event(self):
        result = verify_event(self.mock_request)
        self.assertTrue(result)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()

And that is my code that gets info from request and uses paypalrestsdk.WebhookEvent.verify for verification. It's working on deployment server, but in my test it always returns False. I have several ideas why it is like that: 1. It's because I test it on localhost 2. Maybe webhook can be verified only once or something like that 3. My test work's incorrectly
import paypalrestsdk as paypal
from paypalrestsdk import WebhookEvent
from django.conf import settings
import logging

paypal_api = paypal.configure({
    'client_id': settings.PAYPAL_ID,
    'client_secret': settings.PAYPAL_SECRET,
})


def verify_webhook_signature(data):
    return paypal_api.post(
        "/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature",
        params=data,
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    )


def verify_webhook_signature_using_sdk(data):
    logger = logging.getLogger("info")
    for key, value in data.items():
        logger.info(f"{key}: {value}")
    try:
        return WebhookEvent.verify(
            data.get('transmission_id'),
            data.get('transmission_time'),
            data.get('webhook_id'),
            data.get('event_body'),
            data.get('cert_url'),
            data.get('actual_sig'),
            data.get('auth_algo'),
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error verifying webhook signature: {e}")
        raise


def verify_event(request):
    data = {
        'transmission_id': request.META.get("HTTP_PAYPAL_TRANSMISSION_ID"),
        'transmission_time': request.META.get("HTTP_PAYPAL_TRANSMISSION_TIME"),
        'webhook_id': settings.PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID,
        'event_body': request.body.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(request.body, bytes) else request.body,
        'cert_url': request.META.get("HTTP_PAYPAL_CERT_URL"),
        'actual_sig': request.META.get("HTTP_PAYPAL_TRANSMISSION_SIG"),
        'auth_algo': request.META.get("HTTP_PAYPAL_AUTH_ALGO")
    }

    return verify_webhook_signature_using_sdk(data)

For now, when test completes I get this logs:
[('rsa routines', '', 'bad signature'), ('Provider routines', '', 'RSA lib')]
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_verify_event (webhooks.tests.test_verification.TestVerifyEvent)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/webhooks/tests/test_verification.py", line 30, in test_verify_event
    self.assertTrue(result)
AssertionError: False is not true


